# NSKeyedUnarchiver crashes in iOS 13 Beta (same code works fine for iOS 12 target)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to fetch an array of custom objects (which implement NSCodable) from a local .dat file using NSKeyedUnarchiver and its class method unarchiveObjectWithFile.

The code works fine for a deployment target of iOS 12.x or lower, but crashes reproducibly on an iOS 13 Beta target.  I am fairly certain that the filepath I submit is valid.

The line that breaks it is
`objects = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObejctWithFile:path];`

The console output I receive is: 
`...uncaught exeption 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[Object initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance *`

(with objects and Object being my custom data objects, * being a memory address).

I am grateful for any help or hints as to where this thing might crash.

EDIT: Found a solution (see also my comment replying to aelam):

The class name was identical to a class name in a private framework. The compiler issued a warning at runtime that it wasn't certain which class to use, and it tried to initialize the private class with the "wrong" init method. I renamed the class to get rid of the ambiguity, and made sure that all objects are saved in a new file.

I chalk this up to being a weird bug in iOS 13, since linked classes in my framework should take precedence over private framework classes (at least, that's what seems most intuitive to me).

Comment: `unarchiveObjectWithFile` is deprecated. Use the replacement and consider `requiresSecureCoding`

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: @aelam I did. The class name was identical to a class name in a private framework. The compiler issued a warning at runtime that it wasn't certain which class to use, and it tried to initialize the private class with the "wrong" init method. I renamed the class to get rid of the ambiguity, and made sure that all objects are saved in a new file.